# Js script not working properly in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a carousel using Bootstrap 5, but it seems my js script is not working properly since my carousel does not slide or fade (it just change the image). What am i missing?

I've tried to put the script on the header and also tried to use popper and js scripts separately but with no success

Thanks in advance.

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="features">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselGames" class="carousel slide carousel-dark" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899896/js-script-not-working-properly-in-bootstrap-5#button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselGames" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselGames" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselGames" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/43/200/300" class="carousel-img" alt="..."/>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" class="carousel-img" alt="..."/>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/7667/200/300" class="carousel-img" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <button class="carousel-control-prev carousel-buttons" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselGames" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next carousel-buttons" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselGames" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: When i just copy the page into a snippet and changing the pictures, i get a normal transition.

Comment: Open the browser console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J` on Chrome) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I get no errors on the Chrome console @j08691

Comment: @Raqha So it can be a problem in my browser? I've also tested in firefox and got no transitions

Comment: @Ale i guess, i mean for me its visible. Do you see any transition down in my answer? If you do, it has something to do with the way you show the website in your enviroment, if you dont, its a problem with your browser

Comment: If I dump your code in a codeply, then it works fine. Note though, that you have errors in your HTML. You image tags aren't closed properly, and you failed to close one of your divs

Comment: hey, tks @j08691. I've tried on codeply and didn't get a transition..so probably a problem on my browser(s). Well..that's weird...

Comment: the weird thing is that i can see transitions on other sites using bootstrap

Comment: You have the same issue in every browser you try? And never any console errors? Have you tried in incognito/private mode so that any of your plugin are disabled?

Comment: I've tried chrome, firefox and edge regular and private mode in all of them and got no transitions and no errors on console. I even tried to restart my pc..lol